# Как реализовать функцию Undo/Redo в java

Tags: java, swing, awt

Не могу сделать функции Undo Redo для JTextArea. Как это сделать?

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос больше подробностей, приложите код который у вас есть для решаемой задачи, опишите требуемое поведение

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже был(правда для С++), но позволю себе дать его перевод :

> Я дам еще один ответ, но я думаю, что до сих пор многие об этом не
> знают.
>
> Тема далеко не тривиальна, и поиск в Интернете дает много результатов.
> Многие приложения реализуют операцию "Undo", и существует
> множество вариантов.
>
> Есть 2 паттерна проектирования, которые могут помочь нам здесь:
>
> - `Command`: это воплощение действия
> - `Memento`: которая заключается в сохранении состояния (обычно    подразумевает некоторую форму сериализации)
>
> Паттерн `Команда` широко используется в графических средах,
> поскольку обычно существуют различные способы выполнения действия.
> Например, подумайте об операции *сохранения* в Microsoft Word:
>
> - вы можете нажать на *значок* сохранения
> - вы можете перейти в меню *Файл* и нажать на *Сохранить*
> - вы используете комбинацию клавиш, как правило, CTRL+S
>
> И,
> конечно, *save*, вероятно, реализован в термине *save as*.
>
> Преимущество паттерна `Команда` здесь двоякое:
>
> - вы можете создать стек объектов
> - вы можете попросить каждый объект выполнить операцию `Undo`
>
> Теперь есть различные проблемы, которые присуще операции `Undo`:
>
> - некоторые операции не могут быть отменены (например, рассмотрим `rm`    в Linux или действие *Очистки корзины* в Windows)
> - некоторые операции трудно отменить, или это может быть неестественно    (вам нужно сохранить некоторое состояние, объект
>   обычно уничтожается,    но здесь вам нужно будет фактически сохранить
>   его в команде для    операции Undo)
> - как правило, мы думаем об отмене/повторении как о стеке, некоторые    программы (в основном графические) предлагают отменять элементы,
>   фактически не отменяя то, что было сделано позже, этого гораздо
>   труднее достичь, особенно когда новые действия были построены поверх
>   действия для отмены...
>
> Поскольку существуют различные проблемы, существуют различные подходы
> к решению:
>
> - Для простой Команды вы можете рассмотреть возможность реализации    отмены (например, добавление символа можно отменить, удалив его)
> - Для более сложной команды вы можете рассмотреть возможность    реализации отмены как восстановления предыдущего состояния (именно
>   здесь включается `Memento`)
> - Если у вас много сложных команд, что может означать много `Memento`, которые занимают много места, вы можете использовать подход, который
>   заключается в запоминании только одного снимка(`снапшота`) каждые 10
>   или 20 Команд, а затем повторении Команд с последнего снимка до
>   отмененной команды
>
> На самом деле, вы, вероятно, можете смешивать `Command` и `Memento` по
> желанию, в зависимости от специфики вашей системы и, следовательно,
> сложности любого из них.
>
> Я бы только рассматривал возможность отмены последнего выполненного
> действия для начала (используя тогда стек действий). Функциональность
> отмены любого действия, которое пожелает пользователь, намного
> сложнее.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746076/how-do-i-create-undo-in-c)

Так же рекомендую посмотреть [UndoManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html), [UndoText](https://web.archive.org/web/20100114122417/http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.undo/UndoText.html)